# Getting the Last Matching Value in Record Type By Value in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data structure in BigQuery that looks like this:

```
[{
    sessionID: '123456',
    revenue: 100.00,
    pagesViewed: [
      {hit: 1, val: "a.html"}, {hit:3, val: "b.html"}, {hit:3, val: "c.html?test=AAC"}, {hit:10, val:"d.html?test=CCC"}
    ]
},
{
    sessionID: '5555',
    revenue: 50.00,
    pagesViewed: [
      {hit: 1, val: "a.html"}, {hit:3, val: "b.html?test=123"}, {hit:9, val: "c.html"}, {hit:14, val:"d.html"}
    ]
}]
```

I am trying to get the last test ID for each session. For session A, the last test ID would equal: CCC. For session B, it should equal 123. From there I am trying to get the sum of revenue by final test value

The query I have tried is:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(mnt,r'\?test\=([^&]*)') as TestId,
  SUM(rev) as Revenue
FROM (
  SELECT
    sessionID,
    MAX(CONCAT(CAST(pagesViewed.hit AS string),pagePagesViewed.val)) AS mnt,
    MAX(revenue) AS rev
  FROM
    `table` AS m,
    UNNEST(m.pagesViewed) AS pagesViewed
  WHERE
    pagesViewed.val LIKE "%test=%"
  GROUP BY
    1
  ORDER BY
    1,
    2 ASC)
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
```

However, the output does not match the expected values above. Any help would be appreciated!

Output:

```
Row TestId  Revenue  
1   AAC     100.0    
2   123     50.0
```

Expected

```
Row TestId  Revenue  
1   CCC     100.0    
2   123     50.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your purposes:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT
     ARRAY_AGG(
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(pageViewed.val,r'\?test\=([^&]*)')
       IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY pageViewed.hit DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
   FROM UNNEST(pagesViewed) AS pageViewed
  ) AS TestId,
  SUM(revenue) AS Revenue
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

It returns the last matching 'test' value from the array. You can try it over sample data:

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '123456' AS sessionId, 100.00 AS revenue, ARRAY<STRUCT<hit INT64, val STRING>>[(1, 'a.html'), (2, 'b.html'), (3, 'c.html?test=AAC'), (4, 'd.html?test=CCC')] AS pagesViewed UNION ALL
  SELECT '5555', 50.00, ARRAY<STRUCT<hit INT64, val STRING>>[(1, 'a.html'), (2, 'b.html?test=123'), (3, 'c.html'), (4, 'd.html')]
)
SELECT
  (SELECT
     ARRAY_AGG(
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(pageViewed.val,r'\?test\=([^&]*)')
       IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY pageViewed.hit DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
   FROM UNNEST(pagesViewed) AS pageViewed
  ) AS TestId,
  SUM(revenue) AS Revenue
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

This gives `CCC 100.0` in one row and `123 50.0` in the other as output.